# Flutter + DIO: How to pass options from curl command in a request via DIO?

Tags: flutter, dart, httprequest, nextcloud, dio

I am trying to perform a GET request to a NextCloud server. The NextCloud documentation gives an example how to perform the request with a curl command:

> curl -u username:password -X GET
> 'https://cloud.example.com/ocs/v1.php/...' -H "OCS-APIRequest: true"

How can I put options like -u username:password in dio?
I have read the DIO docs up and down, but I can't figure out the solution...

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)
Or with Dio only use the headers below

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var uname = 'username';
  var pword = 'password';
  var authn = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$uname:$pword'));

  var headers = {
    'OCS-APIRequest': 'true',
    'Authorization': authn,
  };

  var res = await http.get('https://cloud.example.com/ocs/v1.php/', headers: headers);
  if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
  print(res.body);
}
```